# mongoDB dynamically created fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've dynamically created some fields (they aren't in my model). I found my collection with COLLECTION.findById.....

If I want to get paths, it doesn't show dynamically created paths.

```
console.log(result);

{ lv: { name: 'List vlastníctva', exist: false },
  projekt: { name: 'Projektová dokumentácia', exist: false },
  uzemne_rozhodnutie: { name: 'Územné rozhodnutie', exist: true },
  complete: false,
  sctcst: { name: 'ščťčšť', exist: false },
  ctyzy: { name: 'čťýžý', exist: false },
  cssczz: { name: 'čšščžž', exist: false },
  __v: 0,
  _id: 59b916633d77c1cf2958f007 }

console.log(Object.keys(result.schema.paths));

[ 'lv.name',
  'lv.exist',
  'projekt.name',
  'projekt.exist',
  'uzemne_rozhodnutie.name',
  'uzemne_rozhodnutie.exist',
  'complete',
  '_id',
  '__v' ]

console.log(result.lv);
{ name: 'List vlastníctva', exist: true }

console.log(result.cssczz);
undefined
```

in Object.keys aren't dynamically created fields.

[command line + Robo 3T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue37P.jpg)

I can't solve it. In DB it looks that it is saved correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Huh? The right part of your screenshot clearly shows those added fields.

Comment: Yes but I can't get paths of that fields ....only paths of fields that are defined in model

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result.get('cssczz', mongoose.Schema.Types.Object)
```

If you're trying to retrieve field which is not defined in schema you need to tell what it's expected type is.

Alternatively, this could also work:

```
var resultAsObject = result.toObject();
console.log(resultAsObject.csszz);
```

Each time you're trying to retrieve some value from mongoose object it checks schema definition to make sure value will have correct type. To retrieve property which is not in schema you either need to tell mongoose what it's type is, or convert mongoose object to plain JS object first.

Docs:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject